# Excel - Table Header not working in formula

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have a Table called "Table1" in Sheet1. This table has a first row where all the column names are
In Sheet2 I am trying to match the headers against another sheet's headers but the formula

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT("<p><b>Usage</b> - ",PROPER(VLOOKUP(A2,Table1,MATCH(C2,Table1[#Headers],0),FALSE)),"<br />"),"")
```

always returns the error "there is a problem with your formula" whenever I enter the
`[#Headers]` part

Is there a setting I am missing or something? I am using latest Excel

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @SJR Here is the screenshot - https://prnt.sc/q5k5qw

Comment: Looks like you left off a whole bit of the formula? Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: So now your formula has no reference to `[#Headers]`.

Comment: I have edited, screenshot should actually be https://prnt.sc/q5k7ur

Comment: Is CONCAT a formula in the new Excel? Otherwise it works for me in a much older version, at least I don't get errors.

Comment: CONCAT is the replacement to CONCATENATE (which I think is deprecated) - https://prnt.sc/q5kbdj. This is my issue, I cannot see why it wouldn't work and have scoured for an answer

Comment: A similar formula is working in another workbook for me - https://prnt.sc/q5kfjq I really don't understand

Comment: What if you just paste the formula above into your file?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I have solved it. Much appreciated for taking the time to help.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the issue, the Table Range was double named so the same range of data named "Table" and called "Table1".

This must have confused Excel